# Comparing two or more sets of sequences

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

I have observed nurses during 400 episodes of care and recorded the sequence of surfaces contacts in each.

I categorised the surfaces into 5 groups 1:5 and calculated the probability density functions of touching any one of 1:5 (PDF).

```
PDF=[ 0.255202629   0.186199343 0.104052574 0.201533406 0.253012048]
```

I then predicted some 1000 sequences using:

```
for i=1:1000 % 1000 different nurses
    seq(i,1:end)=randsample(1:5,max(observed_seq_length),'true',PDF);
end
```

eg.

```
 seq =     1     5     2     3     4     2     5     5     2     5

stairs(1:max(observed_seq_length),seq) hold all
```

[image]

I'd like to compare my empirical sequences with my predicted one. What would you suggest to be the best strategy or property to look at?

Regards,